# Why wont thymeleaf insert my html block of code?

Tags: html, thymeleaf

This is a very trivial question: why won't thymeleaf connect my html code? I looked at various stackoverflow questions, but I seriously don't get what the issue is here.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
    xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org">

<body>
<div th:replace="header::head"></div>

    <h1>Hello </h1>



</body>


</html>
```

header.html

```
<div th:fragment="head">
    <header>
        <ol>
            <li>Home</li>
            <li>About</li>
        </ol>
    </header>

    <h2>Imported</h2>
</div>
```

File hierarchy

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should move your templates (`index.html` and `header.html`) from `static` folder to the `templates` folder.

Files from `templates` are processed by Thymeleaf.
Files from `static` are served "as is".